# Suspended from reviewing based on a question that has multiple questions

Tags: discussion, support, disputed-review-audits, review-suspension

I got suspended from reviewing because of this review:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/32483540

I marked it as "Needs author edit" because it has multiple problems/questions in it. Someone commented, that it "is still effectively asking a single question". Well but for me it's a bit vague.

Is that really a good question? I mean you could say it's focused but you could also say it's not and for me it's not a good review audit.

Comment: “Is that really a good question?” - The question was clear enough that it received an answer that has 7 upvotes.  Additionally, while this fact was hidden, the question itself also received 6 upvotes and 0 downvotes.  Review bans don’t happen after a single audit failure. Question seems straight forward to me, perhaps, make a habit of opening questions in another tab in the future?

Comment: Alright. Yeah but high upvotes doesn't mean it's a good audit review.

Comment: Doesn’t mean it’s a bad one either, but it doesn’t really matter, because your review suspension isn’t from a single failed audit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is ok post for an audit - most of us should have selected "skip", and those who open posts in a separate window to get more "context" could have selected "looks ok". While there aren't any audits "to check correct usage of 'skip'", but [There is no shame in using "Skip"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252195/there-is-no-shame-in-using-skip).

Is the post on-topic? Absolutely. The memory-model is one of the hardest-to-understand areas in all languages, but that knowledge is absolutely required to write lock-free code. A more theoretical spin on such questions is more suitable for computer science sites, but this particular one is about Java, thus making Stack Overflow the only place to ask on Stack Exchange network.

Does the post contain enough information? I don't know (and believe that should be the case for most of us for this question). The question clearly shows research with multiple related links to the official Java documentation. It is clear enough and readable. In this particular case, I'd expect most reviewers should stop and say: "it's far above my knowledge. It looks plausible, but there isn't any way I can judge that".

Does the post contain one specific question? I don't know, but it definitely contains at least one. Sometimes anyone can judge if a post contains multiple questions (i.e., "how to add a row to SQL DB and print a string to the console"), but in this case it requires an expert to decide if the all question-like statements in the post are really the same scoped enough question or rather set of separate questions covering a broad area. It is quite plausible that future visitors with a similar question should be able to identify if that is a match to their question or not - again those future visitors will be far enough in the quest to understand the memory-model space to make that judgement.

Note that if you are indeed an expert in the memory-model space and your judgement did not match opinions of other visitors - it's ok to disagree. You may want to post a separate question requesting the review ban to be lifted with a clear explanation why that post does not have enough information or too broad (I'm sure "Well, but for me it's a bit vague" will not be enough to convince moderators to lift the suspension).